# Unable to Rename WDI indicator columns while loading data in r?

Tags: r

I am trying to rename resultant indicator columns from WDI package based on the help section (`# Rename indicators on the fly WDI(country = 'CA', indicator = c('women_private_sector' = 'BI.PWK.PRVS.FE.ZS', 'women_public_sector' = 'BI.PWK.PUBS.FE.ZS'))`)

When I use similar example on my requirement it doesn't work.

```
library(tidyvserse)
library(WDI)
```

```
WDI(indicator = c('gdp_per_capita' = "NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.KD",
                  'pop' = "SP.POP.TOTL"),
    start = 2019, end = 2019, extra = TRUE) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(country_code = iso2c, income, gdp_per_capita, pop) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(income)) %>% 
  mutate(income = fct_relevel(income, "Low income", "Lower middle income", "Upper middle income"))
```

Nor this:

```
WDI(indicator = c(gdp_per_capita = "NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.KD",
                  pop = "SP.POP.TOTL"),
    start = 2019, end = 2019, extra = TRUE) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(country_code = iso2c, income, gdp_per_capita, pop) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(income)) %>% 
  mutate(income = fct_relevel(income, "Low income", "Lower middle income", "Upper middle income"))
```

It was working last week when I used a similar example.

Am I doing something wrong or is there some change in the package that is causing this ?

Package version i could see in help: `[Package WDI version 2.7.3 Index]`.

I can rename the columns later but just wanted to understand why this is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

It has started working after package update. Probably a bug in the earlier version.